# import import tensorflow_docs error on Colab

Tags: tensorflow, callback, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I've been using colab for deep learning for a over a month and all of a sudden `import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs` stopped working. Is anyone encountering the same issues???

I'm running tf.**version** 2.8.2

```
> !pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
> 
> import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs   
> import tensorflow_docs.modeling   
> import tensorflow_docs.plots
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-8469b6568dc0> in <module>()
      2 get_ipython().system('pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs')
      3 
----> 4 import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs
      5 import tensorflow_docs.modeling
      6 import tensorflow_docs.plots

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_docs/api_generator/reference_resolver.py in ReferenceResolver()
     86       py_module_names: Union[list[str], dict[str, str]],
     87       link_prefix: Optional[str] = None,
---> 88       physical_path: Optional[dict[str, str]] = None,
     89   ):
     90     """Initializes a Reference Resolver.

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

**UPDATE 01-Sep-2022**

I updated python in colab to 3.9.1 using @Kor suggestion and confirmed it. Then ran:

```
> !pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
> 
> import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs
```

The tensorflow doc completed installation but still threw an error on import:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-15-2bc3446903cd> in <module>
    ----> 1 import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs
          2 import tensorflow_docs.modeling
          3 import tensorflow_docs.plots
          4 
          5 print("Version: ", tf.__version__)

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_docs'
```

Comment: One possible solution that worked for me is using the TensorFlow forked Repo from @Mohammad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/MJAHMADEE/docs
import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs   
import tensorflow_docs.modeling   
import tensorflow_docs.plots
```

Comment: I submitted a pull request in TensorFlow GitHub, which has been approved by one person and is awaiting review by two others. You can use the above commands (my own repo is a fork from the main repo) until confirmation is received. There were no errors on Colab, as I checked.

Comment: That worked for me as well. Thanks! Is this fork from a previous version of TensorFlow Docs?

Comment: You're welcome. It is from the last version; however, some parts that caused problems have been modified based on the changes in its previous version.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too, but sadly I don't have a solution. However, this is what I've tried so far:

- Downgrading to Tensorflow 2.6
- Installing a previous version of `tensorflow_docs` with `!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs@my_version` choosing as `my_version` a commit from a few weeks ago.
- Installing `tensorflow_docs` in a different way, first downloading it with `!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/docs` and then installing it via `!pip install docs/`

All without success.

Anyway from the error it seems it is a problem of the `tensorflow_docs`'`ReferenceResolver`, it looks like it is not able to find the library. However with the following instruction `tensorflow-docs` is found:

```
!pip3 freeze | grep tensorflow
```

Comment: thanks. I tried downgrading TF and reinstalling as well. I did notice that change was recent made on the tensorflow/docs repo within the last 24 hours so maybe this was an unintended consequences that they will fix soon.
I also installed the current version of tensorflow_docs locally to check and it worked fine. This is something CoLab related.

Answer (score 1):

```
---> 88       physical_path: Optional[dict[str, str]] = None,
     89   ):
     90     """Initializes a Reference Resolver.

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

This error is caused by the `dict[str, str]` line. This is [PEP-585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) compliant code that works in Python 3.9, but it looks like Colab is still running Python 3.7, so it's failing.

Feel free to send us PRs adding `from __future__ import annotations` to the affected files if you spot these, but ultimately we run 3.9 internally at Google so these may keep sneaking through.

Some other ideas that you might be able to make work:

- Use a Python 3.9 kernel for colab (e.g. via Google Cloud)
- Strip out type hints with something like [`strip-hints`](https://pypi.org/project/strip-hints/)

Answer (score 1):

I assuming you are using Google Colab. As I struggled the same with Google Colab since the default Google Colab is in Python 3.7. Here's what I did to make Google Colab upgrade to Python 3.9

```
!wget -O mini.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x mini.sh
!bash ./mini.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y jupyter
!conda install -q -y google-colab -c conda-forge
!python -m ipykernel install --name "py39" --user
```

Hope this helps you to move on as I did!

Answer (score 0):

I had also a problem with a script using tensor flow in colab, that had been running for months without any problem.
Suddenly I start having the same error as you mention:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

The script finished in the following line, at the top of the script:

```
from tensorflow_docs.vis import embed
```

I have just commented the line, and the script started working again... :

```
# from tensorflow_docs.vis import embed
```

I hope this may help some of you having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

Open (if you are using Colab)

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_docs/api_generator/reference_resolver.py
```

and add `from __future__ import annotations` at the BEGINNING OF THE FILE and then import

```
import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs
import tensorflow_docs.modeling
import tensorflow_docs.plots
```

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/pull/2116/files